# Decoding H.264/AVC Frames in MP4: What's the Output Format?

Tags: mp4

I am currently working on a personal programming challenge to develop an MP4 decoder using VB.NET and the .NET Framework 4.8.1 as a WinForms application. I have obtained the `ISO 14496-12` documentation, which serves as the basic structure for MP4 files.

At this stage, I have successfully prepared various lists containing frame sizes, chunk positions, and information from the stsc and stts boxes. Additionally, I have been able to identify keyframes within the MP4 files.

However, I have come to realize that the `ISO 14496-12` documentation is not sufficient for decoding the frame bytes, which are encoded in H.264/AVC. To proceed with decoding, I understand that I need to refer to the `ISO/IEC 14496-10` documentation specifically for H.264/AVC.

My question is twofold:

- When decoding the frame bytes according to the documentation, would the output data be in a specific format, such as JPEG (identified by the FF D8 marker), or would it be raw bytes representing pixel data? This clarification would help me. In the former case, I could simply save an image using .NET functions.
- Considering my current progress and the information I have mentioned, do you foresee any need for me to purchase a third documentation source?

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"would the output data be in a specific format, such as JPEG (identified by the `FF D8` marker), or would it be raw bytes representing pixel data?"*

An H.264 decoder should decode to raw YUV by default, although it's generally appreciated for standalone use to have a YUV4MPEG2 mode as well, for easier piping, and to have basic format metadata preserved.

Usually the encoding is in YU420P format. There are many examples of converting (via a `For-loop`) any YUV420p data into RGB data. You can finally encode the newly converted RGB into JPEG.

> *"Do you foresee any need for me to purchase a third documentation source?"*

No, unless you want to also handle audio then you'll need the AAC documentation. 
That is `iso/iec 13818-7`. You can also learn by analysing AAC bytes whilst following the source code of some open-source projects that are decoding AAC data. Articles online also explain structure of AAC. You can still get a result without the ISO document itself (*eg:* read articles from those who repeat its words as they teach about AAC audio's bytes structure).

Comment: Good, that made me confident.